# OnDestroyView of a fragment is never called pressing Back button

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

In a basic application based on fragments navigation, fragment B replaces fragment A. Then I press the back button to return to fragment A and I would hope that OnDestroyView  of fragment B would be called but it is never called.
I use AddToBackStack() in the transaction.
Is it normal?

I use AppCompat 26.0 and Xamarin Android.

**UPDATE**:

It can be easily replicated with any Xamarin example. For example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/FragmentsWalkthrough/

In DetailsFragment.cs, add the following:

```
    public override void OnDestroyView()
    {
        base.OnDestroyView();
    }
```

Then if you add a breakpoint at OnDestroyView, you will see that it is never called even when you press the Back button. In other words, each time I add a fragment, a new instance is created, but never destroyed.

Comment: Could you please show some codes? Or provide a demo which will reproduce your problem. If you use `AddToBackStack()` when you replace A with B, this transaction A->B will be in back stack( destroy A and create B), after you press the back button, it will rollback, destroy B and recreate A, so `OnDestroyView` will be called, and `OnStop` will be called too.

Comment: I have added above an update, a xamarin example is enough.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) a fragment which is part of the backstack is usually kept in `stopped` state and not `destroyed`. `onDestroyView()` is part of the destroy phase and will not be called if the fragment is merely `stopped`.

So yes, that is normal. Try to use `onStop()` instead.

Comment: OnStop is also not called. I can see at SupportFragmentManager.Fragments that the fragment is really removed from the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days, finally I have found the problem. It seems a Xamarin bug. I have changed the Target from Android 8.0 to Android 7.1. I compiled it and it worked fine. Then I changed back to 8.0 again and it started to work fine too.

I could replicate this solution with the Xamarin examples too.